# Cannot log into iMessage or FaceTime from mac

Tags: macos, mac, messages, keychain, facetime

I have two macs, and at some point one of them stopped being able to log into Messages ( just the apple account ) and FaceTime.  The other mac worked fine, but was not using iCloud keychain ( at the time I did not realize this was the issue ).

Later, I activated iCloud keychain on the working mac and FaceTime stopped working there as well so I think this is related. De-activating iCloud keychain does not fix it.  Making a new account does, but this is a pain.  This started I think on Mavericks, and upgrading to Yosemite Beta hasn't fixed it.

My hunch is there is some keychain confusion going on, but I erasing any keychains related to apple hasn't helped either.

This apple discussion shows I'm not the only one, but nobody has a solution.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5472846?start=60&tstart=0

Any ideas?

Thanks!